# jquery - tooltip moves away in position relative

Tags: jquery, css, position, tooltip

I got this ToolTip:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    //Tooltips
    $(".tip_trigger").hover(function(){
        tip = $("body").find('.tip');
        tip.show(); //Show tooltip
    }, function() {
        tip.hide(); //Hide tooltip        
    }).mousemove(function(e) {
        var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coodrinates
        var mousey = e.pageY + 20; //Get Y coordinates
        var tipWidth = tip.width(); //Find width of tooltip
        var tipHeight = tip.height(); //Find height of tooltip

        //Distance of element from the right edge of viewport
        var tipVisX = $(window).width() - (mousex + tipWidth);
        //Distance of element from the bottom of viewport
        var tipVisY = $(window).height() - (mousey + tipHeight);

        if ( tipVisX < 20 ) { //If tooltip exceeds the X coordinate of viewport
            mousex = e.pageX - tipWidth - 20;
        } if ( tipVisY < 20 ) { //If tooltip exceeds the Y coordinate of viewport
            mousey = e.pageY - tipHeight - 20;
        } 
        tip.css({  top: mousey, left: mousex });
    });
});
```

and the CSS:

```
.tip {
    color: #fff;
    background:#1d1d1d;
    display:none;
    padding:10px;
    position:relative;z-index:1000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

How I use:

```
<a class="tip_trigger"><span class="tip">This will show up in the tooltip</span></a>
```

The Problem:
when the tooltip is inside an element with `position: relative`, the tooltip coodrinates changes, and the tooltip moves away...

I guess it happens because the tooltip div is `position: absolute`, so how can I fix that ?

Hope you understand me, my English is not so good....

---

*Edit 1*:

**FULL EXPLANATION WITH IMAGE:**
[image]

---

*Edit 2*:
I uploaded my website so you can see it in live...
the URL is: http://superdown.me/gladiator.
**Put at both fields the value: "admin" (username and password).**

After you login, hover with your mouse at the "37.5%", you'll see it at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `.tip_trigger` position relative:

```
.tip_trigger {
    position: relative;
}
```

And then reposition your `.tip`. Now it will ALWAYS be inside a relatively positioned item and should be consistent.

Comment: That will work, as long as he doesn't care about the mouse position.

Comment: It still doesn't works! look at my question, I uploaded an image that explains better

Comment: @ArielAharonson, after you took idrumgood's solution, you should set top and left attributes to relatively small values. for example: top:10px; lefet:10px;

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute` on your .tip. Going with `position: relative` on `.tip_trigger` only, will make your text flip around.

```
.tip {
    color: #fff;
    background:#1d1d1d;
    display:none;
    padding:10px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eKWJe/3/

**Update**

There's probably another solution to this problem, but you could put your `<span class="tip"></span>` outside of the container. Like this:

```
<body>
  <span class="tip">This will show up in the tooltip</span>
  <div id="header">
      ---
  </div>
</body>
```

Jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ojuras/2/edit

Comment: It still doesn't works! look at my question, I uploaded an image that explains better

Comment: Could you update the fiddle so we can see the issue live, or provide a link to your site.

Comment: I uploaded my website so you can see it in live... the URL is: http://superdown.me/gladiator. Put at both fields the value: "admin" (username and password).

After you login, hover with your mouse at the "37.5%", you'll see it at the top of the page.

Comment: See my updated answer @ArielAharonson
Your game looks cool by the way, keep it up! :)

Comment: OK, your solution is work, that why I changed the JS code to: `tip = $("body").find('.tip');` instead of: `tip = $(this).find('.tip');`, I tried it before.
But if I do that, I can put only 1 tooltip at the page... (or you have a solution?)